# How Pony (ORM) does its tricks?

Tags: python, orm, metaprogramming, dsl, ponyorm

[Pony ORM](https://docs.ponyorm.org/) does the nice trick of converting a generator expression into SQL. Example:

```
>>> select(p for p in Person if p.name.startswith('Paul'))
        .order_by(Person.name)[:2]

SELECT "p"."id", "p"."name", "p"."age"
FROM "Person" "p"
WHERE "p"."name" LIKE "Paul%"
ORDER BY "p"."name"
LIMIT 2

[Person[3], Person[1]]
>>>
```

I know Python has wonderful introspection and metaprogramming builtin, but how this library is able to translate the generator expression without preprocessing? It looks like magic.

[update]

Blender wrote:

> [Here is the file](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/blob/orm/pony/orm/decompiling.py#L52) that you're after. It seems to reconstruct the generator using some introspection wizardry. I'm not sure if it supports 100% of Python's syntax, but this is pretty cool. – Blender

I was thinking they were exploring some feature from the generator expression protocol, but looking this file, and seeing the `ast` module involved... No, they are not inspecting the program source on the fly, are they? Mind-blowing...

@BrenBarn: If I try to call the generator outside the `select` function call, the result is:

```
>>> x = (p for p in Person if p.age > 20)
>>> x.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <genexpr>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pony\orm\core.py", line 1822, in next
    % self.entity.__name__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pony\utils.py", line 92, in throw
    raise exc
TypeError: Use select(...) function or Person.select(...) method for iteration
>>>
```

Seems like they are doing more arcane incantations like inspecting the `select` function call and processing the Python abstract syntax grammar tree on the fly.

I still would like to see someone explaining it, the source is way beyond my wizardry level.

Comment: Presumably the `p` object is an object of a type implemented by Pony that looks at what methods/properties are being accessed on it (e.g., `name`, `startswith`) and converts them to SQL.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/blob/orm/pony/orm/decompiling.py#L52) is the file that you're after. It seems to reconstruct the generator using some introspection wizardry. I'm not sure if it supports 100% of Python's syntax, but this is pretty cool.

Comment: @Blender: I've seen this kind of trick in LISP - pulling this stunt in Python is just plain sick!

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Pony ORM author is here.

Pony translates Python generator into SQL query in three steps:

1. Decompiling of generator bytecode and rebuilding generator AST
   (abstract syntax tree)
2. Translation of Python AST into "abstract SQL" -- universal
   list-based representation of a SQL query
3. Converting abstract SQL representation into specific
   database-dependent SQL dialect

The most complex part is the second step, where Pony must
understand the "meaning" of Python expressions. Seems you are most
interested in the first step, so let me explain how decompiling works.

Let's consider this query:

```
>>> from pony.orm.examples.estore import *
>>> select(c for c in Customer if c.country == 'USA').show()
```

Which will be translated into the following SQL:

```
SELECT "c"."id", "c"."email", "c"."password", "c"."name", "c"."country", "c"."address"
FROM "Customer" "c"
WHERE "c"."country" = 'USA'
```

And below is the result of this query which will be printed out:

```
id|email              |password|name          |country|address  
--+-------------------+--------+--------------+-------+---------
1 |john@example.com   |***     |John Smith    |USA    |address 1
2 |matthew@example.com|***     |Matthew Reed  |USA    |address 2
4 |rebecca@example.com|***     |Rebecca Lawson|USA    |address 4
```

The `select()` function accepts a python generator as argument, and then analyzes its bytecode.
We can get bytecode instructions of this generator using standard python `dis` module:

```
>>> gen = (c for c in Customer if c.country == 'USA')
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(gen.gi_frame.f_code)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                26 (to 32)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (c)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (c)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                0 (country)
             15 LOAD_CONST               0 ('USA')
             18 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             21 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        3
             24 LOAD_FAST                1 (c)
             27 YIELD_VALUE         
             28 POP_TOP             
             29 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   32 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             35 RETURN_VALUE
```

Pony ORM has the function `decompile()` within module `pony.orm.decompiling` which can
restore an AST from the bytecode:

```
>>> from pony.orm.decompiling import decompile
>>> ast, external_names = decompile(gen)
```

Here, we can see the textual representation of the AST nodes:

```
>>> ast
GenExpr(GenExprInner(Name('c'), [GenExprFor(AssName('c', 'OP_ASSIGN'), Name('.0'),
[GenExprIf(Compare(Getattr(Name('c'), 'country'), [('==', Const('USA'))]))])]))
```

Let's now see how the `decompile()` function works.

The `decompile()` function creates a `Decompiler` object, which implements the Visitor pattern.
The decompiler instance gets bytecode instructions one-by-one.
For each instruction the decompiler object calls its own method.
The name of this method is equal to the name of current bytecode instruction.

When Python calculates an expression, it uses stack, which stores an intermediate
result of calculation. The decompiler object also has its own stack,
but this stack stores not the result of expression calculation,
but AST node for the expression.

When decompiler method for the next bytecode instruction is called,
it takes AST nodes from the stack, combines them
into a new AST node, and then puts this node on the top of the stack.

For example, let's see how the subexpression `c.country == 'USA'` is calculated. The
corresponding bytecode fragment is:

```
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (c)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                0 (country)
             15 LOAD_CONST               0 ('USA')
             18 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
```

So, the decompiler object does the following:

1. Calls `decompiler.LOAD_FAST('c')`.
   This method puts the `Name('c')` node on the top of the decompiler stack.
2. Calls `decompiler.LOAD_ATTR('country')`.
   This method takes the `Name('c')` node from the stack, 
   creates the `Geattr(Name('c'), 'country')` node and puts it on the top of the stack.
3. Calls `decompiler.LOAD_CONST('USA')`.
   This method puts the `Const('USA')` node on top of the stack.
4. Calls `decompiler.COMPARE_OP('==')`.
   This method takes two nodes (Getattr and Const) from the stack,
   and then puts `Compare(Getattr(Name('c'), 'country'), [('==', Const('USA'))])`
   on the top of the stack.

After all bytecode instructions are processed, the decompiler stack contains
a single AST node which corresponds to the whole generator expression.

Since Pony ORM needs to decompile generators 
and lambdas only, this is not that complex, because
the instruction flow for a generator is relatively straightforward
- it is just a bunch of nested loops.

Currently Pony ORM covers the whole generator instructions set except two things:

1. Inline if expressions: `a if b else c`
2. Compound comparisons: `a < b < c`

If Pony encounters such expression it raises the `NotImplementedError` exception. But even in 
this case you can make it work by passing the generator expression as a string.
When you pass a generator as a string Pony doesn't use the decompiler module. Instead
it gets the AST using the standard Python `compiler.parse` function.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Great explanation, and an interesting example of an "internal DSL" (domain-specific language) implemented in Python.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dsl+python for more - tagged this question as [dsl].

Comment: Very performant: (1) Bytecode decompiling is very fast. (2) Since each query has corresponding code object, this code object can be used as a cache key. Because of this, Pony ORM translates each query only once, whereas Django and SQLAlchemy have to translate the same query again and again. (3) As Pony ORM uses IdentityMap pattern, it caches query results within the same transaction. There is a post (in russian) where author states that Pony ORM turned out to be 1.5-3 times faster than Django and SQLAlchemy even without query result caching: http://habrahabr.ru/post/188842/

Comment: Is this compatible with pypy JIT compiler?

Comment: I don't tested it, but some Reddit commenter says it is compatible: http://tinyurl.com/ponyorm-pypy

Comment: SQLAlchemy has query caching and the ORM makes extensive use of this feature.  It isn't on by default because its true we don't have a feature in place to link the construction of a SQL expression to the position in source code which it is declared, which is what the code object is really giving you.  We could use stack frame inspection to get the same result but that's just a little too hacky for my tastes.   Generation of SQL is the least critical performance area in any case; fetching rows and bookkeeping changes is.

Comment: Is there a fundamental problem with inline if-then-else and comparisons?

Comment: @randomsurfer_123 probably not, we just need some time to implement it (maybe a week), and there are other tasks that are more important to us.