# How to ignore PonyORM generator expressions in nose-tests coverage

Tags: nose, coverage.py, ponyorm

I'm using `nosetests --cover-erase --with-cover  --cover-branches` to run my test cases.

I'm using PonyORM to delete set of objects. Below is how my code looks like.

```
@db_session
def remove_all_stuff(self):
    delete(j for j in MyEntityClass if j.deleted == True)
```

When I calculate the coverage, even though I execute `remove_all_jobs`. PonyORM doesn't execute the generator expression inside `delete(`.

How do I ignore the generator expression and still check that the `delete(` is called?

---

What I found.

1. `# pragma: no cover` -> cannot be used because I need to cover `delete`
2. `[report] exclude_lines` in `.coveragerc` also doesn't work for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some other suggestions to the [coverage.py issue about this](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/685#issuecomment-442862490).

---

Some other possibilities of how to handle this more gracefully:

You can set the coverage.py pragma regex so that some lines are automatically pragma'd:

```
[report]
partial_branches = 
    pragma: no branch
    \.select\(lambda
```

Now any line that matches either of the two regexes will be considered partial-branch, so your line is recognized even without a comment.

You can separate the definition of the lambda or generator expression from the line that uses them:

```
to_select = lambda p: p.nom_d_exercice.lower().startswith(chaine.lower())    # pragma: no branch
return Praticien.select(to_select)
```

or:

```
to_delete = (j for j in MyEntityClass if j.deleted == True)  # pragma: no branch
delete(to_delete)
```

This isolates the non-run code to its own line, so you don't run the risk of turning off coverage measurement on a line that truly needs it.

Comment: I've copied content from github, so it's easier for anyone else to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `# pragma: no branch` directive in this case. This will ignore the generator expression.

```
@db_session
def remove_all_stuff(self):
    delete(j for j in MyEntityClass if j.deleted == True)  # pragma: no branch
```

if you are using `lambda` to select, format those to a new line and use `# pragma: no cover`

**Why this happens?**

This is because PonyORM doesn't execute the generator expressions and sometimes lambdas. It generates SQL by decompiling and analysing the abstract syntax tree of these python expressions.

More Info: [How Pony (ORM) does its tricks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115713/how-pony-orm-does-its-tricks)